# Need formatted XSL data from given XML data

Tags: xml, xslt

```
        <PQWorklist>
          <userID>DT77214</userID>
          <password>&&&&&&</password>
          <hostAddress>%%%%%%</hostAddress>
          <hostPort>&&&&&%%%%%</hostPort>
          <DST>
            <PQWorklist>
              <transaction id="2012-07-30-16.38.49.403260T01" children="N" hasParent="Y">
                <permission>Update</permission>
                <id>2012-07-30-16.38.49.403260T01</id>
                <createTime time="Y">2012-07-30T16:38:49:403260-05:00</createTime>
                <businessArea>CSMHCDV</businessArea>
                <type>ISSUE</type>
                <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                <TEAM>CATCHALL</TEAM>
                <WSL7/>
                <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
                <iconName/>
                <status>CATCHALL</status>
                <queue>CATCHALL</queue>
                <priority>999</priority>
                <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
                <VIP>N</VIP>
                <suspended>N</suspended>
                <amountType/>
                <amount>0.0000</amount>
                <assignedTo>DT77214</assignedTo>
                <lockedBy>DT77214</lockedBy>
                <process>Y</process>
                <workStep status="CATCHALL">Issue Status Queue</workStep>
                <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
                <externalSystem>
                  <host/>
                  <executable/>
                  <parameters/>
                  <procedure/>
                </externalSystem>
                <PEND>CATCHALL</PEND>
                <RULE>99</RULE>
                <ICT1>PCP Change</ICT1>
                <ITYP>Change Requests</ITYP>
                <MLOB>HMO</MLOB>
                <OUID>DT64253</OUID>
                <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                <RGRP>COMM*H</RGRP>
                <RMEM>10021*01</RMEM>
                <RPRV>PCP4</RPRV>
                <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
                <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
                <STPT>2012-07-30-16.38.46.000000</STPT>
                <STRT>2012-07-30-16.38.20.000000</STRT>
                <UIID>20120730-163846-DT64253</UIID>
              </transaction>
              <transaction id="2012-09-01-07.35.56.311400T01" children="N" hasParent="Y">
                <permission>Update</permission>
                <id>2012-09-01-07.35.56.311400T01</id>
                <createTime time="Y">2012-09-01T07:35:56:311400-05:00</createTime>
                <businessArea>CSMHCQA</businessArea>
                <type>ISSUE</type>
                <CFLG>2</CFLG>
                <TEAM>CATCHALL</TEAM>
                <WSL7/>
                <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
                <iconName/>
                <status>CATCHALL</status>
                <queue>CATCHALL</queue>
                <priority>999</priority>
                <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
                <VIP>N</VIP>
                <suspended>N</suspended>
                <amountType/>
                <amount>0.0000</amount>
                <assignedTo>DT77214</assignedTo>
                <lockedBy/>
                <process>Y</process>
                <workStep status="CATCHALL">Issue Status Queue</workStep>
                <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
                <externalSystem>
                  <host/>
                  <executable/>
                  <parameters/>
                  <procedure/>
                </externalSystem>
                <PEND>CATCHALL</PEND>
                <RULE>99</RULE>
                <ICT1>PROVIDER PROSPECTUS</ICT1>
                <ICT2>MEMBER PROSPECTUS</ICT2>
                <ITYP>REQUEST</ITYP>
                <OUID>DT64642</OUID>
                <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
                <SBJT>Unknown</SBJT>
                <STPT>2012-09-01-08.32.21.000000</STPT>
                <STRT>2012-09-01-07.56.52.000000</STRT>
                <UIID>20120901-083221-DT64642</UIID>
              </transaction>
               </PQWorklist>
            </DST>
        </PQWorklist>
```

the above XML is i need to transform into below XML using xsl sheet can any one help on     this...

in above XML we need to remove duplicate tag that is    so that i will get what i expected...

Please help me on this...

```
    <PQWorklist>
      <userID>DT77214</userID>
          <password>&&&&&&</password>
          <hostAddress>%%%%%%</hostAddress>
          <hostPort>&&&&&%%%%%</hostPort>
           <transaction id="2012-07-30-16.38.49.403260T01" children="N" hasParent="Y">
            <permission>Update</permission>
            <id>2012-07-30-16.38.49.403260T01</id>
            <createTime time="Y">2012-07-30T16:38:49:403260-05:00</createTime>
            <businessArea>CSMHCDV</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
            <TEAM>CATCHALL</TEAM>
            <WSL7/>
            <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
            <iconName/>
            <status>CATCHALL</status>
            <queue>CATCHALL</queue>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
            <VIP>N</VIP>
            <suspended>N</suspended>
            <amountType/>
            <amount>0.0000</amount>
            <assignedTo>DT77214</assignedTo>
            <lockedBy>DT77214</lockedBy>
            <process>Y</process>
            <workStep status="CATCHALL">Issue Status Queue</workStep>
            <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
            <externalSystem>
              <host/>
              <executable/>
              <parameters/>
              <procedure/>
            </externalSystem>
            <PEND>CATCHALL</PEND>
            <RULE>99</RULE>
            <ICT1>PCP Change</ICT1>
            <ITYP>Change Requests</ITYP>
            <MLOB>HMO</MLOB>
            <OUID>DT64253</OUID>
            <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
            <RGRP>COMM*H</RGRP>
            <RMEM>10021*01</RMEM>
            <RPRV>PCP4</RPRV>
            <RTYP>PCP</RTYP>
            <SBJT>Member</SBJT>
            <STPT>2012-07-30-16.38.46.000000</STPT>
            <STRT>2012-07-30-16.38.20.000000</STRT>
            <UIID>20120730-163846-DT64253</UIID>
          </transaction>
          <transaction id="2012-09-01-07.35.56.311400T01" children="N" hasParent="Y">
            <permission>Update</permission>
            <id>2012-09-01-07.35.56.311400T01</id>
            <createTime time="Y">2012-09-01T07:35:56:311400-05:00</createTime>
            <businessArea>CSMHCQA</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
            <TEAM>CATCHALL</TEAM>
            <WSL7/>
            <commentsExist>Y</commentsExist>
            <iconName/>
            <status>CATCHALL</status>
            <queue>CATCHALL</queue>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <priorityIncrease>0</priorityIncrease>
            <VIP>N</VIP>
            <suspended>N</suspended>
            <amountType/>
            <amount>0.0000</amount>
            <assignedTo>DT77214</assignedTo>
            <lockedBy/>
            <process>Y</process>
            <workStep status="CATCHALL">Issue Status Queue</workStep>
            <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
            <externalSystem>
              <host/>
              <executable/>
              <parameters/>
              <procedure/>
            </externalSystem>
            <PEND>CATCHALL</PEND>
            <RULE>99</RULE>
            <ICT1>PROVIDER PROSPECTUS</ICT1>
            <ICT2>MEMBER PROSPECTUS</ICT2>
            <ITYP>REQUEST</ITYP>
            <OUID>DT64642</OUID>
            <RCAL>CREATED</RCAL>
            <SBJT>Unknown</SBJT>
            <STPT>2012-09-01-08.32.21.000000</STPT>
            <STRT>2012-09-01-07.56.52.000000</STRT>
            <UIID>20120901-083221-DT64642</UIID>
          </transaction>
    </PQWorklist>
```

Comment: And what have you tried up to now?

Comment: one more thing i want mention is ,often i am getting the response as like this

Comment: And have you read Stack Overflow rules on asking questions? Quote: Questions asking for code **must** demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: sorry , i am new to working on xml and xsl , Please help me on this..

Comment: no need to take care  of  element data , only the way the tags are formed like below xml that is only importent...

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a translation service. You **have** to show us that you put some effort in trying to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PQWorklist>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PQ/PQWorklist/hostAddress"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PQ/PQWorklist/hostPort"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PQ/PQWorklist/userID"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PQ/PQWorklist/password"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::transaction"/>
        </PQWorklist>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: some times i am getting more than one transaction element also , can you please suggest me how to write xsl for loop to track the transaction tag with elements,i have changed my post...

Comment: I have edited my answer since you've edited your question. It doesn't matter how many transaction tags are there, the template will get them all. In your input, there are 2 transaction tags, but your required output has 3. How is that?

Comment: as I said the template will get all `transaction` nodes.

Comment: Lamson, i tried what you have sent but i am getting above result , i need to remove the  <DST> <PQWorklist> elements from my actual output so can you please help me on this...

Comment: The output xml should have a root element for it to be a valid XML. I have modified my answer but I have retained `PQWorklist` as the root element.

Comment: is there any way to delete PQWorklist  and to make valid xsl...can you please suggest me

Comment: if you insist on having an output with no root element, you can go ahead and remove that `PQWorklist`. But if you use that output as xml somewhere else, it will be an invalid xml.